# Hibernate annotations relations

Tags: java, hibernate

Right now I'm working on small project, submitting very simple jobs and I'm working on saving this to the database. Consider this case :

```
public class Myjob{
   int id;
   int name;
   MyJobConfiguration configuration;
   //etc
}

public class MyJobConfiguration{
     //bunch of configuration fields
}
```

I have these configurations in separate class as you see, which means I want to add/update/delete configurations independent of my job object.

My goal was to create configuration first and then while creating a job assign an existing configuration to it.

So more than one job can use same configuration object.

How would I do that? I've already got an idea how to do it in the database, I would connect primary key of configuration to foreign key in the myJob class, but it seems different in hibernate. Does anyone have example how to do that ?

I found this one as I thought that is it http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation/ but it seems not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a one to many relationship, not a one to one as described in the linked article.

You've got a clear idea of how you want the relationship to work, which is nice.  Based on what you've said, I would make MyJobConfiguration look like this:

```
public class MyJobConfiguration {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "configuration")
    private List<MyJob> jobs;

    //bunch of configuration fields
}
```

and MyJob look like this:

```
public class Myjob{
    int id;
    int name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "configuration_id", nullable = false)
    MyJobConfiguration configuration;
    //etc
}
```

I might even be inclined to give MyJob a constructor that takes a MyJobConfiguration instance, and make the MyJob() default constructor package-private scoped so that Hibernate can still use it, but callers can't.

Comment: thank you for your response. What is the reason behind creating myjob constructor that takes myjobconfiguration instance and making it package-private?

Comment: You would make the `MyJob(MyJobConfiguration config)` constructor public and the default constructor `MyJob()` package private.  The reason for doing this is to prevent people coding against the entities from calling the empty constructor (since the config is required).  But Hibernate needs the default constructor to load objects from the DB, and it can still use the default constructor with the more restrictive scope.